# Error while installing core ML tools

Tags: python, ios, coreml

I am trying to convert a caffe model to core ML model. 
Please find the error while running **pip install coremltools**

```
Collecting coremltools
    Using cached coremltools-0.4.0-py2.7-none-any.whl
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.2 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from coremltools)
    Collecting protobuf>=3.1.0 (from coremltools)
      Using cached protobuf-3.3.0.tar.gz
    Collecting six>=1.9 (from protobuf>=3.1.0->coremltools)
      Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from protobuf>=3.1.0->coremltools)
    Installing collected packages: six, protobuf, coremltools
      Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
        DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
        Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
        prefix=options.prefix_path,
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
        requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
        paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
        renames(path, new_path)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
        shutil.move(old, new)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
        copy2(src, real_dst)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
        copystat(src, dst)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
        os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
    OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/5z/5hfw98ks677_r5rqm498kq1c0000gn/T/pip-DMhcCb-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I am new to machine learning. Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 1):

As error said - operation is not permitted. I'm Linux not Mac user - but it's probably because you try to do this without root privilages.

You can try `sudo pip install coremltools`. But generally speaking installing development libraries system-wide is not best practice.

You should definitely use **virtualenv**.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the virtual environment method and it is shown as coremL is installed successfully. Successfully installed coremltools-0.4.0 numpy-1.13.1 protobuf-3.3.0 six-1.10.0. But again when I try to import core ml tools it is showing as import core ml tools ImportError: No module named core ml tools.                                                                                                          
Now pip install coremltools tells:
Requirement already satisfied: coremltools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: sudo  pip install -U coremltools --ignore-installed